# Google Web Designer on Windows XP

Tags: google-web-designer

I've installed Google Web Designer on Windows XP, and saw this error:

> The procedure entry point GetSystemDefaultLocaleName could not be located in the dynamic library KERNEL32.dll

What can I do?

Comment: Same problem here. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Christian yes, `windowsXp` not supported!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that it won't support XP.

Here are the minimum system requirements, according to [their documentation](https://support.google.com/webdesigner/answer/3232604?hl=en&ref_topic=3249465):

> ### Operating system
>
> #### Windows requirements
>
> - Windows 7
> - Windows 8

Comment: When I launch Web Designer! Nothing is shown! Plain GUI with ash white color :(

Answer (score 1):

I think it does not support Windows XP. I installed in Windows 7. No issues. The error you have got is mainly caused by misinterpreted operating system -- that's described as a possible cause  [in Microsoft's support knowledge base](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/142606):

> The application is misinterpreting the operating system version and is trying to call a procedure in the Windows 95 or Windows 98 version of the Dynamic Link Library (DLL) that is unavailable in Windows NT version 4.0 or Windows 2000.

Answer (score 0):

Windows XP is not supported. See the [system requirements](https://support.google.com/webdesigner/answer/3232604).

[image]